# Illegal state when using shared pref to mute media

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, android-mediaplayer, illegalstateexception

I have a settings activity that's uses a shared pref to mute my mediaplayer:

```
  cb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbmutestartup);
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
    boolean checkedFlag = sharedpreferences.getBoolean("checkboxstate",false);
    cb.setChecked(checkedFlag);

    cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            if (cb.isChecked()) {

                editor.putBoolean("soundMute",true);
                editor.putBoolean("checkboxstate", true);
                editor.commit();


                Log.i("Sound: ", "Activated");

            }else{
                editor.clear();
                editor.commit();
                Log.i("Sound: ","Deactivated");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The pref for my checkbox state works which is still in the settings activity. But then soundMute pref when activated then returning to the media player throws an Illegal state. The illegal state is showing in my log cat in the onPrepare method of my media player.

This is my media player class which is also where I call for the shared pref:

```
ublic class harropMediaplayer {
MediaPlayer player;
String media;
Context c;
public harropMediaplayer(String media,Context c){
    this.media = media;
    this.c = c;

}

public void volumeSetting(){

////MY NEW VOLUME MUTE METHOD INCLUDING THE FETCH SHARED PREF
   
  SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = 
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c);

    boolean bnSoundMute = sharedpreferences.getBoolean("soundMute",false);

    if(bnSoundMute==true){
mutevol();
        Log.i("sound","muted");

    }else{

volmax();
        Log.i("sound","max vol");
    }
}
public void plysound() {
    player = App_Objects.mp;

    Log.i("Url", media);
    try {
        player.setDataSource(media);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {

        player.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Log.i("Sound playing", "Ok");
    player.start();
}

public void stopplying(){
    player.stop();
    player.release();
}
public void volmax(){
    player = App_Objects.mp;
    player.setVolume(1,1);
}
public void mutevol(){
    player = App_Objects.mp;
    player.setVolume(0,0);
}
}
```

### Edit

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
                                                                                at android.media.MediaPlayer._setVolume(Native Method)
                                                                                at android.media.MediaPlayer.playerSetVolume(MediaPlayer.java:1826)
                                                                                at android.media.PlayerBase.baseSetVolume(PlayerBase.java:117)
                                                                                at android.media.MediaPlayer.setVolume(MediaPlayer.java:1821)
                                                                                at com.example.harrops.h20droidapp2.harropMediaplayer.mutevol(harropMediaplayer.java:71)
                                                                                at com.example.harrops.h20droidapp2.harropMediaplayer.volumeSetting(harropMediaplayer.java:33)
                                                                                at com.example.harrops.h20droidapp2.Splash$1.onDataChange(Splash.java:84)
                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeeq.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzegl.zzbwe(Unknown Source)
                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzegr.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: `illegal State` means `IllegalStateException`? If yes, then show the stacktrace.

Comment: yes ill try to add it now thanks @VladMatvienko

Comment: Added @VladMatvienko thanks for the help

Comment: ok, it basically looks like the player is in wrong state (released?) when you try to set it's volume.

Comment: so what would you suggest to fix. remove the release from stop playing method?

Comment: I suggest you to set the volume before starting the player. Not before you initialized it (*prepared*)

Comment: as simple as that? ill try that now n get back to you

Comment: ive tried moving the call of the volume setting to just before player.start still the same. the mute function does work. it is only the very next time you start the app that it crashes with the illegal state. untill you then try to unmute it and it does the same thing again

Comment: also tried to call it after media player is called in my splash activity

Comment: fixed i moved it to straight after the on prepare then added catch illegalstate to the block. thanks